# Running a Python script from its icon in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python

Let's say I have a Python script sitting in a folder I just opened with the graphical file manager in standard Ubuntu. What would be the quickest way to run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe "properties -> set executable [x] ?

while struggling with how to import JVC's weird .mod format to standard .mpeg...

Answer (score 2):

mark it as executable first,ensure you have python installed,then double click on it

you can mark files executable with the following command

```
chmod a+x filename
```

where filename here is the name of the file you want to make executable

Comment: Also, make sure that the script has the hash-bang line at the beginning (like `#!/usr/bin/env python`): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-bang

Comment: well,the permissions also matter,you don't want unauthorized users running your script,do you?